# When can I omit "das" when using a nominalized verb in subject position?

Tags: infinitive, nominalization, gerund

I have trouble translating English gerunds to German. After consulting some grammars, I've found some ways to do it. Two of them is to either use an infinitive construction or a nominalized verb with or without "das". Examples:

1a) Lesen macht Spaß (Nominalisiertes Verb).

1b) Das Lesen macht Spaß (Nominalisiertes Verb).

1c) Es macht Spaß zu lesen (Infinitiv).

---

2a) Gehen ist gesund (Nominalisiertes Verb).

2b) Das Gehen ist gesund (Nominalisiertes Verb).

---

3a) Singen (in der Dusche) macht Spaß (Nominalisiertes Verb).

3b) Das Singen (in der Dusche) macht Spaß (Nominalisiertes Verb).

3c) In der Dusche zu singen macht Spaß (Infinitiv).

---

a) Can it be that omitting "das" (e.g. "gehen") is more general and "das Gehen" more specific?

b) Are there cases when using the "infinitive construction" is better? For example in the case of 3c?

Comment: Just a suspicion: I would assume a lot of texts intended for learners of German are *artificially injected* with articles in front of substantiated verbs to signal "Hey! Watch out, this might be a substantive!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are all correct. The definite article is optional and only used if you wanted to point a finger to a specific action:

> Warum **übst** du nicht zuhause weiter? – **Das Singen** stört meine Frau.

Here, it should be *Das Singen* as you point to the specific action in *üben* which disturbs your wife.

---

For simple gerunds, both the *infinitive noun* and the *zu-infinitive* are equivalent. A problem arises when the *zu-Infinitive* has adverbs or particles:

> Er empfahl zu sparen. / Er empfahl Sparen.
>
> Er empfahl, mehr zu sparen. / Er empfahl vermehrtes Sparen.

Especially *nicht* is evil:

> Er empfahl, nicht zu sparen. / Er empfahl Geldausgeben.

Modal particles can make the transformation impossible as they change the meaning in mysterious ways:

> Er empfahl, bloß zu sparen.

He advocated saving money, by all means.

> Er empfahl bloß Sparen.

He advocated saving money, I had hoped for better advice.

This problem arises from placing the comma. If it was behind *bloß* in the first sentence, the meaning would be the same as the second.